# How to change this.variable in jquery function?

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular5

How to change this.variable of class AuthDirective in jquery function?

maybe stupid question but, I need to use Jquery events and to change/to work with angular variables.

```js
import { Component, Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppGlobal                    } from '../../../app.global';
declare var $:any;

@Component({
  selector    : 'authorization',
  templateUrl : './auth.directive.html'
})
export class AuthDirective {
  isCaptcha : boolean = false;
  constructor(
    public  app : AppGlobal
  ) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    $('.sign-up-label').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      this.isCaptcha = true; // NOT IN THIS CONTEXT, IN THAT CONTEXT
    })
  }
}
```

{{isCaptcha}} is always false

```html
<div class="form-group ta-web-right mt-3" *ngIf="isCaptcha">
  <re-captcha (resolved)="resolved($event)"></re-captcha>
</div>
```

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve value of `this` from outer context by assigning it to variable:

```
ngOnInit() {
    var self = this;
    $('.sign-up-label').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      self.isCaptcha = true;
    })
```

}

Comment: I tried
{{isCaptcha}}
              <div class="form-group ta-web-right mt-3" *ngIf="isCaptcha"> ,,,, ngIf = false and isCaptcha = false; it doesn't change variables in template

Answer (score 0):

store the outer context like this `let self = this;` and then it doesn't conflict with the local context.

replace your `function` like this

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange) {
    let self = this;
    $('.sign-up-label').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      self.isCaptcha = true; // NOT IN THIS CONTEXT, IN THAT CONTEXT
    })
  }
```

Comment: I tried {{isCaptcha}} <div class="form-group ta-web-right mt-3" *ngIf="isCaptcha"> ,,,, ngIf = false and isCaptcha = false; it doesn't change variables in template

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10  try replacing this.isCaptcha = true; with self.isCaptcha  = true;

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10 what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: try to see changing of variable in *ngIf for ex.   When .on executes I can detect changing within current function but can't detect it in angular template engine

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10, first of all, I won't suggest Jquery inside Angular 4.It's not a best practice. you can use ng-bootstrap library. I suspect it's because of ngOnInit which will be called only once. Try replacing ngOnInit with ngOnChanges()

Comment: ng-bootstrap has not worthy animation/ Question is namly about Jquery, bad or not it's my own solution